# How to reference object by another variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm learning php and I ran into the following head-scratcher:

I have 2 objects, let's say

```
class Fruit {
public $weight;
}

$apple = new Fruit();
$apple->weight = 1;

$banana = new Fruit();
$banana->weight = 2;
```

Later on, from I get some input from the user as a variable (like, which fruit do you like best?):

```
$user_preference =  'apple';
```

Now, how can I reference the correct object dynamically? How to get something like

```
echo $user_preference->weight;
```

?

Comment: `echo ${$user_preference}->weight;` or `echo $$user_preference->weight;`. See [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). It's not exactly a recommended feature to use in most cases though.

Comment: Remember, if this is web based, when yo get the data from the user the original Objects will have been destroyed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a map (usefull when data is retrieved from a db for example)

```
$apple = new Fruit();
$apple->weight = 1;

$banana = new Fruit();
$banana->weight = 2;

$fruitMap = ['apple'=>$apple,'banana'=>$banana];

$user_preference =  'apple';

echo $fruitMap[$user_preference]->weight;
```

But do a check if the key exists

Comment: This is definitely a safer way to go rather than using variable variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) :

```
<?php
class Fruit {
    public $weight;
}

$apple = new Fruit();
$apple->weight = 1;

$banana = new Fruit();
$banana->weight = 2;

$user_preference =  'apple';

//   vv---------------- Check this notation
echo $$user_preference->weight;  // outputs 1
```

[Test it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/270c82b1008585fd2abad34d2c421ba6621813c9)

---

Note that **this can lead to security breaches** because

1. Never trust user inputs.
2. Never trust user inputs especially when it comes to control your code execution.
3. Never trust user inputs.

Imagine you do `echo $$user_input;` and user input is `database_password`

To avoid it, you need to sanitize user inputs, in example :

```
<?php
class Fruit {
    public $weight;
}

$apple = new Fruit();
$apple->weight = 1;

$banana = new Fruit();
$banana->weight = 2;

$allowed_inputs = ['apple', 'banana'];

$user_preference =  'apple';

if (in_array($user_preference, $allowed_inputs))
{
    echo $$user_preference->weight;  // outputs 1
}
else
{
    echo "Nope ! You can't do that";
}
```

But this is at the cost of typing more code. [ka_lin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648496/8398549) is safer and easier to maintain

Comment: @Dilek why do you suggest that change? Isn't that the key to the answer, variable variables?

Comment: @Cid, could you elaborate a bit on the *this can lead to security breaches* please?

Comment: is it ? I didnt see it in example https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_objects.asp sorry will remove. and I market it as usefull.

Comment: @jibsteroos about security: when you use a User input as a variable name, user can enter name of a unexpected variable. imagine that.

Comment: @Amin Shojai yes, sure, and Cid had originally posted a small explanation, but deleted it. Given it is pretty important (hence bolded), it might make sense to add a sentence to the answer to explain this risk.

Comment: This can lead to security breaches because 1) Never trust user inputs. 2) Never user inputs especially when it comes to control your code execution. imagine you do `echo $$user_input;` and user input is `database_password`